# Sbt native packager doesn't create service script file

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I've used native packager to deploy a play api as a RPM package. The package created lacks the `/etc/init.d/` folder and script.

How can I debug this situation ?

Here is an extract from the build.sbt :

```
lazy val myApp = (project in file("api"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, RpmDeployPlugin, SonarPlugin)
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(  
    organization := "com.organization",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
    ...)
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq( etc...)
```

Comment: Do you have multiple main classes? If yes then try to specify one like `mainClass in Compile := ...`

Comment: It's actually a multiproject App with a play framework project inside. Do you know How I can define the mainClass for the PlayFramework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I had was that I was missing `SystemVplugin` and `RpmDeployPlugin` (I used `RpmPlugin` only)

```
lazy val `my-api` = (project in file("my-api"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, RpmDeployPlugin, SystemVPlugin)
  ...
```